# why i can't parse xml in javascript?

Tags: javascript, firefox, xml-parsing

hello i have problem to parse xml..
i have xml like this :

```
<tejemahan>
  <kategori> komputer </kategori>
  <hasil> aplikasi komputer </hasil>
</terjemahan>
```

**Edited:**
 
xml above I get in that way :

```
   var url="http://localhost:8080/inlinetrans/api/translate/"+userSelection+"/"+hasilStemSel+"/"+hasilStem;
   var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
   client.open("GET", url, false);
   client.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
   client.send(null);

   if(client.status == 200)
       alert("the request success"+client.responseText);
   else
       alert("the request isn't success"+client.status+""+client.statusText)

  }
```

and this is my code to parse an xml file above :

```
this.loadXML = function (){
   var url = http://localhost:8080/coba/api/artikan/"+sel+"/"+hasilStemSel+"/"+hasilStem
   xmlDoc=document.implementation.createDocument("","",null);
   xmlDoc.load("url");
   xmlDoc.onload= this.readXML;
  }

  this.readXML = function() {
        alert(xmlDoc.documentElement.tagName);
 alert(xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes[0].tagName);
 alert(xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes[1].tagName);
 alert(xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes[0].textContent);
 alert(xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes[1].textContent);

     }
```

i can execute this code

```
xmlDoc=document.implementation.createDocument("","",null); 
xmlDoc.load("url");
```

but why i can't execute this code
 xmlDoc.load = this.readXML ???

Comment: Can you provide the code that calls loadXML?

Comment: I call the loadXML after making a request to the server

Comment: Why are you using this approach? XHR is better supported across browsers. "document.load() is a part of an old version of the W3C DOM Level 3 Load & Save module. Can be used with document.async to indicate whether the request is synchronous or asynchronous (the default). As of at least Gecko 1.9, this no longer supports cross-site loading of documents (Use XMLHttpRequest instead)." — https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.load

Comment: I've answered your question and shown you how to get an XML document from your `XMLHttpRequest`. By using its `responseXML` property you don't need to do any parsing.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the onload handler assignment before the load() call. If you call load() first, the onload event will happen before you have assigned a handler to handle it. Like this:

```
xmlDoc=document.implementation.createDocument("","",null);
xmlDoc.onload= this.readXML;
xmlDoc.load("url");
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I second David Dorward's suggestion: use `XMLHttpRequest` instead, which will work in all major browsers. Code is below.

Secondly, your `readXML` function is flawed, since most browsers will include whitespace text nodes within the `childNodes` collection, so `xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes[0]` will actually be a text node and have no `tagName` property. I would suggest using `getElementsByTagName()` or checking the `nodeType` property of each node as you iterate over `childNodes`.

Thirdly, your XML is not valid: the `<tejemahan>` and `</terjemahan>` do not match, although this may be a typo in your question.

```
var url = "http://localhost:8080/coba/api/artikan/"+sel+"/"+hasilStemSel+"/"+hasilStem;

var readXML = function(xmlDoc) {
    alert(xmlDoc.documentElement.tagName);
    var kategori = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("kategori")[0];
    alert(kategori.tagName);
};

var createXmlHttpRequest = (function() {
    var factories = [
        function() { return new XMLHttpRequest(); },
        function() { return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0"); },
        function() { return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0"); },
        function() { return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }
    ];

    for (var i = 0, len = factories.length; i < len; ++i) {
        try {
            if ( factories[i]() ) {
                return factories[i];
            }
        }
        catch (e) {}
    }
})();

var xmlHttp = createXmlHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {
        readXML(xmlHttp.responseXML);
    }
};

xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlHttp.send(null);
```

Comment: it can't still work Tim..i used my code above and i get childNode length but i can't read the contents of xml

Comment: @user495688: Could you be a bit more sepcific about what error you're getting and where? Perhaps a test page we can see?

Comment: @user495688: I've added an example use of `getElementsByTagName()` to my example `readXML` function.

Comment: @user495688: Also I missed off a double quote in the declaration of `url`, which I've now fixed.